# sqlserver trims char data when using a subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, trim, subquery

I'm having problems with a select in SQLSERVER 2008.

I have a table with a char(32) column as PK. Whenever i select from this table, the pk result always have the 32 characters, even if the data has less than 32 characters. I.E: (Replace dots with blank spaces) 'id1.....................').

But if i'm selecting data from another table, and sub-selecting using that id, the data comes trimmed.

Example code:

```
select id,
(select description from othertable where othertable.id = mytable.id) as description
from mytable
```

This query will get the id data trimmed ( 'id1' instead of 'id1.......................').

I haven't found any information in what is causing this or how to avoid it.

This problem only seems to be happening in a specific schema of SQLSERVER, it does not happen in ORACLE or other engines.

Comment: What is the data type of `description` in `othertable`?

Comment: Same as the other char(32)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ANSI_PADDING is set to 'True'

[SET ANSI_PADDING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx)

If that doesn't work, you can alter your query to add the spaces back

```
select LEFT(id + SPACE(32),32),
(select description from othertable where othertable.id = mytable.id) as description
from mytable
```

Comment: May not be relevant if `othertable.description` is a `varchar` rather than `char`, hence my question to him/her.

Comment: That is why I added the altered query.